# Get root object using JSONPath query

Tags: json.net, jsonpath

Is there any syntax for a json path query to return the root object?

To quote Goessner on the subject:

> Since a JSON structure is usually anonymous and doesn't necessarily have a "root member object" JSONPath assumes the abstract name $ assigned to the outer level object.

So I'd really expect just "$" to return the root object... But it doesn't.  It returns false.

I need a way to get the root object in a query (seems silly I know but the application I am using only allows me to specify a jsonpath query to access items in JSON).

Comment: You've tagged your question [tag:json.net].  If you really are using this package, it does support the `"$"` operator, as shown in https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm

Answer (score 5):

`$` does return the root object for Jayway, Gatling and Nebhale.

Looks like the equivalent in Goessner is `$..`